# How can I get one part from a response in java?

Tags: java, json, string

my response looks like following:

```
{"result":1,"redirect":"","user_login":"Woldo","user_id":"4358970","session_id":
"ab89JBFLrYJ,6-lXKnv-T9wC481"}
```

I only want the `session_id` part `ab89JBFLrYJ,6-lXKnv-T9wC481` , I was using

```
ReadSession.substring(86, 113);
```

but whenever someone with a longer username logs in I get in trouble because it is out of the 113 range.

thanks!

Comment: Use a JSON parser: [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098)

Answer (score 1):

The data is in the JSON format. Use the [JsonReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonReader.html) class to parse it, then extract the session_id value

Answer (score 1):

Better to convert this input string into JsonObject and then extract `session_id` key from that object. If you are using `org.json.JSONObject` class then you can try this code

```
String input = //your input
  try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
      String sessionID = jsonObject.getString("session_id");
    }catch (JSONException e){

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something silly like this for general use

```
String string = "{\"result\":1,\"redirect\":\"\",\"user_login\":\"Woldo\",\"user_id\":\"4358970\",\"session_id\":\n" +
"\"ab89JBFLrYJ,6-lXKnv-T9wC481\"}";
       int index = string.indexOf("session_id");
       String id = string.substring(index+14, string.length()-2);
        System.out.println(id);
```

Comment: thank you that was working for me very good, I might check out Json parsing later but for now its working with your solution thanks!